# File not ignore not excluded not assumed unchanged Git

Tags: git, ignore

There's a configuration file that I want out of my projects as to not have permanent conflicts with all my co-workers.

At first I put in my .gitignore and it worked just fine, however being ignored it wasn't on the server and I had to rewrite it everything I changed branches or pulles since it was deleted every once in a while.

So I read the man more carefully and started using exclude and that worked fine, for like 2 hours, then I pushed, pulled and the file was modified all over. Now it's not even excluded anymore and shows up everytime  I change it in my tracked files.

So, I tried a index --assume-unchanged which worked until I pulled, also it won't let me change branches telling me I have a conflict.

Every so often if I try to checkout the file or remove it git will tell me he is

```
    unable to .... name/of/the/file
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? 
All the other files that either exclude or ignore are ignore or excluded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the file keeps showing back up is that your coworkers are not ignoring it.

If you're going to ignore files in Git, you have to make sure everyone agrees on what will be ignored; it's impossible (or at least extremely difficult) to have different ignore rules on different clones of a shared repo.

The procedure for ignoring an already-committed file:

1. Remove the file from the repo: `git rm --cached /path/to/myfile`
2. Commit.
3. Add the file to `.gitignore`
4. Add `.gitignore` to the repo if it isn't already
5. Commit and push.

Now, when your coworkers merge your changes, these two commits will remove the config file from their repo but leave the actual file intact on their systems, and ensure the file is in their .gitignore so that their future commits will not add the config file back to the repo.

Comment: Thank you :) I guess we all wanted to get started using it without really applying the same rules